# old look to new stucco

Tags: stucco

I am trying to match a custom stucco interior which is full of cracks, some very pronounced and deep... and thats the look I want to achieve. Altogether it gives the place a very warm, old-world feel. It is a rough-ish texture, color coat appears to be quite thick (in spots, maybe up to 1") There are scores of articles on how to keep stucco from cracking... I want to find one which tells me HOW TO GET THE STUCCO to crack.

Comment: Are you sure it's stucco and not plaster?

Comment: Could you provide a photo? To me it sounds like a very high percentage of Portland cement was in the mix , this will cause cracking especially if the surface is uneven or not uniform thickness. The mix hardens to the point of cracking as all cement mixtures get harder over time and crack.